# php mysqli update set doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a php script with a mysql database. I have the UPDATE SET query with prepared statement. But I get the echo update correct changed when I submit the form but when I look in the database the data is not changed.

What is going wrong?

thanks in advance.

my code is:

```
include 'connect.php';


$sql = "UPDATE names SET name = ?, lastname = ?, address = ?, place = ?, telephone = ?, description = ? WHERE id = ?  ";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("issssss", $id, $name, $lastname, $address, $place, $telephone, $description);


 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
 $address = $_POST['address'];
 $place = $_POST['place'];
 $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
 $description = $_POST['description'];
 $stmt->execute();


if (! $sql) {
    echo "Data not changed";
} else{
    echo "Data correct changed";
    }
$stmt->close();
mysqli_close($link);
```

The form code is:

```
<form  action="update.php" method="POST" >
        <input type="text" name="id"  placeholder="id">
            <br /><br />
        <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="name">
            <br /><br />
        <input type="text" name="lastname"  placeholder="lastname">
            <br /><br />
        <input type="text" name="address"  placeholder="address">
            <br /><br />
        <input type="text" name="place"  placeholder="place">
            <br /><br />
        <input type="text" name="telephone"  placeholder="telephone">
            <br /><br />
        <textarea  rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="description" name="description"></textarea>
            <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bind param  `not in a sequence` you need to put your `id at last`

```
<?php
$sql = "UPDATE names SET name = ?, lastname = ?, address = ?, place = ?, telephone = ?, description = ? WHERE id = ?  ";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssi", $name, $lastname, $address, $place, $telephone, $description,$id);
```

And use `$stmt->affected_rows` to check data is updated or not

```
$stmt->execute();
//You can get the number of rows affected by your query
$nrows = $stmt->affected_rows;
if (!$nrows) {
     echo "Data not changed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reorder code like this

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

// this one from top put here
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssi", $name, $lastname, $address, $place, $telephone, $description,$id);

// and then execute sql
$stmt->execute();

if (! $sql) {
    echo "Data not changed";
} else{
    echo "Data correct changed";
}
$stmt->close();
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: This will not  effect any thing . You can define it any where in your code check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php.

Comment: fixed bind, sorry no saw it